# Extend TypeScript / JavaScript native objects in a safe way with Sweet.JS hygienic macros (like extension methods)

Tags: javascript, typescript, extension-methods, sweet.js

The https://www.sweetjs.org library allows to transform JavaScript code. I wonder if it would be possible to use it to extend native objects like Array, Object, String etc. in a safe way, without attaching anything to their prototype.

It seems like sweet.js should be able to transform this JS code

```
{ a: 1 }.isEmpty()
```

Into

```
Extensions.isEmpty({ a: 1 })
```

And the implementation could be

```
Extensions.isEmpty = (o) => {
  if ('isEmpty' in o) return o.isEmpty()
  for (const k in o) if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) return false
  return true
}
```

But I'm not sure **what code should I write in Sweet.JS to make that work**?

P.S.

And with TypeScript it should work even better. We can trick TypeScript into thinking that our objects are extended by giving it false declaration below, and then after TypeScript compilation apply Sweet.JS compilation.

```
declare global {
  interface Object {
    isEmpty(): boolean
  }
}
```

So we get all the correct typings for extensions, and our native objects would stay perfectly clean.

Comment: I would advise not using SweetJS in production as it's not our job to decide what should and shouldn't be in the language. If however this is for a project i would recommend reading the Typescript transformer documentation, adding the type to the global.d.ts and transforming Object.isEmpty into a function call isEmpty(object) using the instead of SweetJS. Doing this will give you more control as you have access to the types which SweetJS wont have.

Comment: @ShanonJackson Didn't knew about TypeScript transformers, thank you, will check it out!